# webMathematica is to Mathematica as _________ is to Matlab

Tags: matlab

webMathematica lets you put Mathematica tools on the web easily.  What is the Matlab equivalent?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with the question. I read the scope "defined by the community" and I still don't see the problem. He is not asking a recommendation, he just wants to know if something equivalent exists.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, I don't think there is any web version / web tools by Matlab.